# RSS Feed Shows NULL When Asking For Thumbnail

Tags: rss, blog, simplepie

I am pulling in posts from separate WP installs on separate URLs. I have everything I want except for the thumbnail. My theme supports thumbnails but when I ask for the thumbnail it is showing me NULL. Anyone know why this may be happening? When I `var_dump($item)` it shows NULL for my thumbnails. All my posts on that sep. URL do have a featured image.

functions.php

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

The RSS Page

```
<?php
  include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php');
  $rss = fetch_feed(PATH_TO_MY_URL);
  if(!empty($rss)):
    $maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity(4);
    $rss_items = $rss->get_items(0, $maxitems);
  endif;
?>

<?php
      if ($maxitems == 0) :
        echo 'No News.';
      else :
        foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) : ?>

          <div class="post-block">
            <figure>
              <a href="#">
                <?php
                  if ($enclosure = $item->get_enclosure()) :
                        echo $enclosure->get_thumbnail();
                    endif;
                ?>
              </a>
            </figure>
            <h3 class="mbs"><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $item->get_permalink(); ?>" class="link-color-1"><?php echo $item->get_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <?php echo $item->get_description(); ?>
            <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $item->get_permalink(); ?>" class="btn mtxs btn-sm btn-color-3">Read Full Article &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
          </div>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember WP feeds to have any care for thumbnails feature. There is some handling for `enclosure` meta (seems dusty, don't even remember what that is), but from quick test it seems to ignore thumbnails.

Why do you *expect* exactly for thumbnails to just appear in feed?

Unless I am missing something, it seems you would need to hook in and add thumbnail information to the feed yourself.